# Make div responsive at certain screen size

Tags: html, css

I want that at different screen sizes for example at 480px width and lower that the #homepageRightImg goes under #homepageLeftImg. This is the code that I'm using, but it doesn't seem to be working. What am I missing or doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />    
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<!--[if IE 8]><body class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><body> <!--<![endif]-->

<div id="homepageContentGlobal" class="homepageContentGlobal" style="display:none"></div>
<div></div>

        <div id="homepageLeftNav" class="homePageNav">
            <div class="content" id="homepageLeftMenuTitle">
                <p class="title">My<br>Test</p>
                <div class="subTitle">
                      <a href="http://www.google.com/" class="button">Learn more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="homepageLeftTitle" class="homepageTitle">

            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="homepageRightNav" class="homePageNav">
           <div class="content" id="homepageRightMenuTitle">
                <p class="title">My<br>Title</p>
                <div class="subTitle">
 <a href="http://www.google.com/" class="button">Learn more</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="homepageRightTitle" class="homepageTitle">


            </div>
        </div>
<div>
        <ul id="homepageLeftImg" class="homepageCol">
<li><img src="test.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="test.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="test.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="test.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="test.jpg"/></li>
       </ul>


<ul id="homepageRightImg" class="homepageCol">
<li><img src="test.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="test.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="test.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="test.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="test.jpg"/></li>       </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
     .homepageContentGlobal {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 98;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
     }
    .homepageCol li {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        display: block;
     }

     #homepageLeftImg {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 50%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
     }

     #homepageRightImg {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        right: 0;
        left: 50%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

     #homepageLeftNav {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 50%;
        width: 50%;
        z-index: 3;
        cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    }

   #homepageRightNav {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        left: 50%;
        width: 50%;
        z-index: 3;
        cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
   }

.homepageTitle {
        cursor: default;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 100%;
     }
   .homepageNavLink{}

    #homepageLeftMessage {
    z-index: 100;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
     }

     #homepageLeftMessage #subLogo {
    z-index: 100;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
     #homepageLeftImg {
    display:block;
     }

   #homepageRightImg {
    display:block;
    }
}
```

Comment: where to html code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added an example how to use css other than `position elements.`

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#homepageLeftImg,
#homepageRightImg {
  float: left;
  /* Keeps both the div to align side by side to each other */
  width: 50%;
  /* 50% width to both equates to 100% */
  height: 100%;
}

#homepageLeftImg li,
#homepageRightImg li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#homepageLeftImg li img,
#homepageRightImg li img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
  #homepageLeftImg,
  #homepageRightImg {
    width: 100%;
    /* Below 480px the width will be 100% and the images will come in stakced view. */
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="homepageLeftImg" class="homepageCol">
  <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x800/red/fff&text=This+is+Dummy+left+Image"></li>

</ul>


<ul id="homepageRightImg" class="homepageCol">
  <li><img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x800/blue/fff&text=This+is+Dummy+right+Image"></li>
</ul>
```

You are missing the `width:100%` and also add `top:100%` to the #homepageRightImg

> **Add the following css in your media query:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
     #homepageLeftImg {
    display:block;
width:100%;
     }

   #homepageRightImg {
    display:block;
width:100%; top:100%:
    }
}
```

Also seeing your css code I see a lot `poisition:absolute` elements.
I suggest **not to use position:absolute** on every element as it destroys the structure.

Comment: I've included the HTML. Btw, the CSS is external

Comment: The main problem is with the position absolute which is used at every element.. Please dont use position absolute if you are a beginner in css coding and make the structure following standard rules which will surely bring perfect result as you want. Also, your html structure will break as its not proper.

Comment: So, instead of using position absolute what other tags should I use to have the images at the desired position, left images on the left side of the page and the right images on the right side.

Comment: Added an example code above. Do check .. Using float css properties you can achieve all the things.. No need to use positions for this structure..